# Prove that $\sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x (x+1)(x+2)} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2 (n+1) (n+2)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that $\displaystyle \sum_{x=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x (x+1)(x+2)} = \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2 (n+1) (n+2)}$.

I tried using the partial fraction decomposition $a_j = \frac{1}{2j} - \frac{1}{j+1} + \frac{1}{2(j+2)}$, but I don't see how that helps.

Comment: See the answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630360/series-of-inverses-of-binomial-coefficients

Comment: @xyzzyz I am wondering how to get the answer from what I got.

Comment: See also: [Formula for $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2108596)

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. *From what you wrote* one may observe that
$$
\frac{1}{j (j+1)(j+2)}=\frac{1}{2j} - \frac{1}{j+1} + \frac{1}{2(j+2)}=\frac12\left(\frac1j - \frac1{j+1}\right)+ \frac12\left(\frac1{j+2} - \frac1{j+1}\right)
$$ then noticing that terms *[telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)*.

---

**Remark**. One may also write
$$
\frac{1}{j (j+1)(j+2)}=\frac12\frac1{j(j+1)}-\frac12\frac1{(j+1)(j+2)}
$$ then by summing terms telescope giving

> $$
> \sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j (j+1)(j+2)}=\frac12\frac1{1\times(1+1)}-\frac12\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)}= \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{2 (n+1) (n+2)}
> $$

as announced.

Comment: Where does the $\dfrac{1}{4}$ come from?

Comment: @Puzzled417 I don't see $\frac14$ in my answer.

Comment: Do you see my question?

Comment: It comes from the fact that $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac12\left(\frac1j - \frac1{j+1}\right)=\frac12-\frac12\frac1{(n+1)}$ and  $\sum_{j=1}^n \frac12\left(\frac1{j+2} - \frac1{j+1}\right)=\frac12\frac1{(n+2)}-\frac14$, thus the constant term is $\frac12-\frac14=\frac14$. Do you see it?

Answer (score 1):

More generally,
if
$x_{(n)}
=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{x_{(n)}}-\dfrac1{(x+1)_{(n)}}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+1+k)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x+k)}\left(\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac1{x+n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x+k)}\left(\dfrac{n}{x(x+n)}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n} (x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{x_{(n+1)}}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{1}{j_{(n+1)}}
&=\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac1{n}\left(\dfrac1{j_{(n)}}-\dfrac1{(j+1)_{(n)}}\right)\\
&= \dfrac1{n}\left(\dfrac1{1_{(n)}}-\dfrac1{(m+1)_{(n)}}\right)\\
\text{or}\\
\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n} (j+k)}
&= \dfrac1{n}\left(\dfrac1{n!}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (m+1+k)}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

If
$n=2$,
this becomes
$\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{2} (j+k)}
= \dfrac1{2}\left(\dfrac1{2!}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{1} (m+1+k)}\right)
$
or
$\sum_{j=1}^m \dfrac{1}{j(j+1)j+2)}
= \dfrac1{4}-\dfrac1{2(m+1)(m+2)}
$

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{m(m+1)(m+2)}&=\frac12\left(\frac{(m+2)-m}{m(m+1)(m+2)}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{m(m+1)}-\frac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)}\right)
\end{align}$$

So, letting $a_m=\frac{1}{m(m+1)}$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{m(m+1)(m+2)}&=\frac12\left(a_m-a_{m+1}\right)
\end{align}$$

from which we find

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{m(m+1)(m+2)}&=\sum_{m=1}^n \frac12\left(a_m-a_{m+1}\right)\\\\
&=\frac12(a_1-a_{n+1})\\\\
&=\frac14-\frac12 \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!