# Harmonic series partial sum

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

According to Beyer (1987) the following progression is called harmonic series: $$\frac {1} {a_{1}},\frac {1} {a_{1}+d},  \frac {1} {a_{1}+2d},...$$

How it can be calculated the partial sum of the above mentioned sequence?

Comment: I don´t see that there exists a closed form for the partial sum.

Comment: @callculus what about approximation?

Comment: Search for "Harmonic numbers". Note however, that your sequence is more general, related to "Digamma function"

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you for your comment. Can you please provide some material reagrdinf this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of terms for $n=0,1,...,m$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^m \frac{1}{d(a_1/d+n)} =\frac{1}{d} \left(\psi \left(m+1+\frac{a_1}{d}\right) -\psi \left(\frac{a_1}{d}\right) \right)$$

Where $\psi$ is the Digamma function.

Use the definition:

$$\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z-1}{(n+1)(n+z)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please provide some information how it is derived? P.S. sorry, if my comment is weird, i don't have background in this topic.

Comment: @David, try using the definition I provided, and you will see that the formula is true

Comment: Thank you. My aim is to find a closed-form expression for the finite series. Is it possible?

Comment: @David, I have written it in my answer above

Comment: The Digamma function is expressed in terms of infinite sum, but my aim is to find closed-form expression. Thank you.

Comment: @David, this is a closed form expression. It is not possible to get something "more closed from" for general $a_1,d$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85886/discussion-between-david-and-yuriy-s).

Comment: Please have a look. Thank you for your support. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003278/partial-sum-of-complex-series

Answer (score 3):

Yuriy S gave the only possible closed form for the summation.

For large $n$, for sure, you could use series expansions and get from
$$S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{a+i\,d}=\frac 1d \left(\psi \left(n+1+\frac{a}{d}\right)-\psi \left(\frac{a}{d}\right) \right)$$
$$S_n=\frac{\log(n)-\psi \left(\frac{a}{d}\right)}{d}+\frac{2 a+d}{2 d^2 n}-\frac{6 a^2+6 a d+d^2}{12
   d^3 n^2}+\frac{2 a^3+3 a^2 d+a d^2}{6 d^4
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$

Using $a=\pi$, $d=e$ and $n=10$, the exact result would be $\approx 1.03107$ while the above series expansion would give $\approx 1.03113$.

Comment: Please have a look. Thank you for your support. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003278/partial-sum-of-complex-series

Comment: @David. No idea about this other one. I am quite skeptical about even an approximation. Even the case $a=\alpha=0$ makes the problem more than difficult (at least to me).

Comment: Do you mean both of them?

Answer (score 1):

**The Harmonic Series**

The partial sum of the standard [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) is given by
$$
H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\tag1
$$
This can be extended to a function that is analytic except at the negative integers
$$
H(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+z}\right)\tag2
$$
The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) gives the asymptotic expansion
$$
H_n=\log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}-\frac1{252n^6}+\frac1{240n^8}-\frac1{132n^{10}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{12}}\right)\tag3
$$
where $\gamma=0.57721566490153286060651209$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

---

**The Series in the Question**
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{a+(k-1)d}
&=\frac1d\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\frac ad+k-1}\\
&=\frac1d\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{\frac ad+k-1}-\frac1{\frac{a-d}d+k-1+n}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac1d\left(H\!\left(n+\frac ad-1\right)-H\!\left(\frac ad-1\right)\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
using the extension in $(2)$.

Formula $(2)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2565358) allows us to compute $H\!\left(\frac ad-1\right)$ for rational $a$ and $d$, while formula $(3)$ above allows us to approximate $H\!\left(n+\frac ad-1\right)$ for large $n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Please have a look. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3003278/calculating-or-approximating-sum-i-1n-frac1-ai-1di-and-sum

Comment: Could you, please, support in order to calculate or approximate the sums represented in the above mentioned link?