# Calculating or approximating $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1} {(a+(i-1)d)^i}$ and $\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1-(i-1)\alpha} {(a+(i-1)d)^i}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How it can be calculated or approximated the following partial sums:
$$S_n=\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1} {(a+(i-1)d)^i},$$
 $$S_n=\sum _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1-(i-1)\alpha} {(a+(i-1)d)^i},$$
where $0<\alpha<1$, $0<a<1$.

Comment: What's complex about it?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I mean sophisticated.

Comment: Look up https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function

Comment: Sometimes there's no "nice" closed form. You can represent such sums as integrals, or approximate them for large or small parameters, etc. Mathematics is rich in opportunities

Comment: @YuriyS Hurwitz zeta function is defined for complex $i$, right?

Comment: @David, isn't $i$ the summation index? It can't be complex, it needs to be an integer

Comment: @YuriyS Right, but in the wikipedia material it is mentioned that zeta function is defined for complex arguments $s$.

Comment: @David, summation index is not the argument. Please read carefully.

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, the summation index is defined by $n$, which isn't in exponent. Here for both series summation index is in exponent.

Comment: It's not the summation index, it's the summation limit