# Calculate the following series using telescoping

Tags: real-analysis, telescopic-series

I have the following series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(k-1)!}{(k+N)!},\quad\text{where }N \in \mathbb{N}. $$

I have found out that the series is equal to

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \biggl(\frac{1}{k}\cdot \frac{1}{k+1}\cdot _{...} \cdot \frac{1}{k+N}\biggr)$$

I also know that for $N=1$ we can use partial fraction expansion and we get a telescoping sum of $1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} + ... + \frac{1}{k+1}$ which leaves $1$ if $k$ is heading to $\infty$.

Does anyone have any idea how I can go about doing this ?

Comment: Start by looking at $\frac{1}{k(k+1)} - \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)}$. If that's not enough, look at $\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)} - \frac{1}{(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}$ too.

Comment: Sorry but that really didn't help.
I'm still going in circles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate sum for $k\ge 1\in\mathbb N\quad\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac1{i(i+1)(i+2)...(i+k)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213294/how-to-calculate-sum-for-k-ge-1-in-mathbb-n-quad-sum-limits-i-1-infty-frac1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid a division by $0$, you should really start at $k=1$. Using @DanielFischer's hint, the telescoping goes as$$\begin{align}\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{1}{k\cdots(k+N)}&=\frac1N\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{k+N-k}{k\cdots(k+N)}\\&=\frac1N\sum_{k\ge1}\left(\frac{k+N}{k\cdots(k+N)}-\frac{k}{k\cdots(k+N)}\right)\\&=\frac1N\sum_{k\ge1}\left(\frac{1}{k\cdots(k+N-1)}-\frac{1}{(k+1)\cdots(k+N)}\right)\\&=\frac1N\left(\left.\frac{1}{k\cdots(k+N-1)}\right|_{k=1}-\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k\cdots(k+N-1)}\right)\\&=\frac1N\left(\frac{1}{N!}-0\right)\\&=\frac{1}{N\cdot N!}.\end{align}$$

Comment: This is brilliant.  
But can you please explain how you got $N!$ at the end.

Comment: @V1C10USG4M3R See edit.

Answer (score 3):

The neat thing about
$p_n(x)
=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)
$
is that is telescopes in both
numerator and denominator.

$\begin{array}\\
p_n(x+1)-p_n(x)
&=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+1+k)-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)-\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)\\
&=(x+n)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x+k)-x\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x+k)\\
&=((x+n)-x)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x+k)\\
&=n\prod_{k=0}^{n-2}(x+1+k)\\
&=np_{n-1}(x+1)\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{p_n(x+1)-p_n(x)}{n}
&=p_{n-1}(x+1)\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac{p_{n+1}(x)-p_{n+1}(x-1)}{n+1}
&=p_{n}(x)\\
\text{and}\\
\dfrac1{p_n(x)}-\dfrac1{p_n(x+1)}
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+1+k)}\\
&=\dfrac1{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x+k)}-\dfrac1{\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{x+n}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}-\dfrac{x}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{(x+n)-x}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{p_{n+1}(x)}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac1{n}\left(\dfrac1{p_n(x)}-\dfrac1{p_n(x+1)}\right)
&=\dfrac{1}{p_{n+1}(x)}\\
\text{or}\\
\dfrac1{n-1}\left(\dfrac1{p_{n-1}(x)}-\dfrac1{p_{n-1}(x+1)}\right)
&=\dfrac{1}{p_{n}(x)}\\
\end{array}
$