# Value of a telescoping series

Tags: real-analysis, telescopic-series

Calculate the value of the following series

$\begin{align} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2\cdot(k-1)+1} \cdot \frac{1}{2\cdot(k)+1} \cdot \frac{1}{2\cdot(k+1)+1} \cdots \frac{1}{2\cdot(k+N)+1} \end{align}$

Where $N \in \mathbb{N}_0$

This should be similar to the telescoping series in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3463448/719642).

And the answer should be $\begin{align} \frac{2^{N-1}}{N+1}\cdot\frac{N!}{(2N+1)!} \end{align}$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you already know how to proceed, just write it down.

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac1{(2k-1)\dots(2k+2N+1)}
&=
\frac1b\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a+b-a}{(2k-1)\dots(2k+2N+1)}
\\&=
\frac1b\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{a+b}{(2k-1)\dots(2k+2N+1)}
- \frac{a}{(2k-1)\dots(2k+2N+1)}
\\&\stackrel{\text{?}}{=}
\frac1b\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k-1)\dots(2k+2N-1)}
- \frac{1}{(2k+1)\dots(2k+2N+1)}
\end{align}

Expanding the last expression we have

$$\left\{
\begin{align}
a+b &= 2k+2N+1\\
a &= 2k-1
\end{align}
\right.
$$

from which it follows that $b= 2(N+1)$. Notice that what matters in the last step is that $b$ does not depend on $k$.

Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101881/discussion-on-answer-by-fimpellizieri-value-of-a-telescoping-series).